# Some Images Are Missing in wordPress

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, elementor

I'm designing a website, using WordPress, using elementor page builder, when I was on my localhost all images were shown but when I move it to the web some images won't show up and some will show.
i tried to re upload the image and didn't work, i tried to deactivate all the plugin and active it and  nothing changed
this is the address

http://einbaghdad.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure that you changed base url in wp-options table in databse.

in some cases you may add image somewhere and give it custom src so it will try to load image from your local host.

you can inspect the images that doesn't load and look at src attribute. so you can see the problem for sure.

Answer (score 1):

The fix may be the following: 
1. Elementor > Settings 
2. Select Advanced tab
3. Set 'CSS Print Method' to 'Internal Embedding'
4. Goto Home page and verify it is rendered properly. 
5. Repeat step 1 and 2 above. 
6. Set 'CSS Print Method' back to 'External File'
 These 6 steps force to regenerate elementor external CSS files to have correct domain path.